# Preserving line break when assigning cell to multi line string value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell into which I entered a multiline value (an address), using alt + enter to insert line breaks. I want that address shown in another cell too. But when I simply assign that second cell to the value of the first cell, it seems like the line breaks are discarded.

What is the logic behind this? And how do I preserve the line breaks?

[image]

Comment: You should enable Wrap Text in cell. Suggest you mark your replay as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :)

The default behavior is that Excel ignores break lines when displaying a text string in a cell. This can be seen by typing the following in a cell.

```
="line1" & CHAR(10) & "line2"
```

The ampersand concatenates the string parts and CHAR(10) evaluates to a break line character. But as default the line is displayed as one line in the cell.

However if enabling *Wrap Text* for that cell, it will be displayed in two lines.

[image]

When typing in a cell and pressing alt + enter, Excel automatically enables *Wrap Text* for that cell.